# How to square-form a dataframe with pair index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON data like:

```json
a={('A', 'B'): 0.8333333333333334, ('A', 'C'): 0.5, ('B', 'C'): 0.625}
```

I need to draw a heatmap based on that data set. but the dataframe I obtained by

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(a,index=['value']).T.reset_index()
```

is like:

[image]

and this seems can not be used to draw a heat map. And the result dataframe should be looked like this:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':{'A':1,'B':0.83333,'C':0.5},'B':{'A':0.83333,'B':1,'C':0.625},'C':{'A':0.5,'B':0.625,'C':1}})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
a = {('A', 'B'): 0.8333333333333334, ('A', 'C'): 0.5, ('B', 'C'): 0.625}
```

you can convert to Series and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to get a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.Series(a).unstack()
```

output:

```
          B      C
A  0.833333  0.500
B       NaN  0.625
```

but this gives only single combinations. If you want both ways, [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with the [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (T):

```
df = df.combine_first(df.T).fillna(1)
```

output:

```
          A         B      C
A  1.000000  0.833333  0.500
B  0.833333  1.000000  0.625
C  0.500000  0.625000  1.000
```

For your heatmap, you can use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df)
```

output:

[image: heatmap]